# Trying to pass data to a flask app with just a html button

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I have a webpage which displays a table with the contents of a database, this is done with flask and sqlite3.

I want to add a button beside each row that sends a request to flask to run a function that e.g. deletes the corresponding element from my database, and then just reloads my page.

This is my html:

```
{% for d in data %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ d[0] }}</td>
  <td>{{ d[1] }} </td>
  <td><button class="delete" type="button" id="{{ d[2] }}">DELETE</button></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Where d[2] is the id in the database.

So basically when a button is pressed it should invoke a python function, something like:

```
@app.route("/delete")
def delete():
   # some code to parse the id
   db.execute('DELETE FROM someTable WHERE id=(?)', id)
   return redirect("/")
```

and then I think I could add an eventListener to each button that listens for a click and calls the function while somehow passing it the id, something like:

```
let deletebuttons=document.querySelectorAll(".delete");
      for (let i = 0; i < deletebuttons.length; i++) {
        deletebuttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
          $.post("/delete")
        })
      }
```

This is where I'm stuck... From my limited understanding of jQuery I can use $.post to send a request to flask and invoke my delete function, I can't figure out how to pass data to said function tho. I guess I could put my button inside a form with the id as a hidden value and retrieve it with request.form.get? Can I do this without using forms?

Answer (score 1):

Use some javascript to achieve this.

```js
// select all buttons
document.querySelector('delete').forEach(each => {
    // for each one, attach an eventlistener of onclick
    each.onclick = () => {
        // send request to your backend delete url
        fetch("http://backendurl/delete", {
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: {...}
            body: JSON.stringify({each.id}),
        });
    };
});
```

and modify your backend:

```
from flask import request
@app.route("/delete", methods=["DELETE"])
def delete():
    body = request.json
    db.execute('DELETE FROM someTable WHERE id=(?)', body.id)
    return redirect("/")
```